# What is the correct way to calculate \multicolumn size when using tabularx?

Tags: tables, tabularx, multicolumn

What is the correct way to determine the correct size for use with `p{}` needed by `\multicolumn` to get the size correct?

The problem is this: I want to use `tabularx` and also use `\multicolumn`. To do that, I have to give \multicolumn an exact size to use. And this is the problem. In complicated table, where I can have one table inside another, and a row that extends to few columns, the calculations are getting hard.

It become harder to figure the correct size, and if I change the table later, I have to change the code again.

The first example below shows that X can't be used with \multicolumn to make it extend to more than one column:

```
\documentclass[10pt,notitlepage]{article}%
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}|l|Y|@{}}\hline
 column 1 &
 {\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}Y|Y|Y@{}}\hline
      \lipsum[75] & \lipsum[75] &  \lipsum[75] \\\hline
      \multicolumn{3}{X}{\lipsum[75]}
  \end{tabularx}
 }
 \\\hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

So have to use `p{}`. Nothing else would let it extend to the other columns.

But `p` wants a size. after some trial and error, here is one that gets close to the size needed

```
\documentclass[10pt,notitlepage]{article}%
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}|l|Y|@{}}\hline
 column 1 &
 {\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}Y|Y|Y@{}}\hline
       \lipsum[75] &  \lipsum[75] &   \lipsum[75] \\\hline
      \multicolumn{3}
        %this calculation below is needed, and not sure if it is correct now
        {p{.9\dimexpr \textwidth-4\arrayrulewidth-8\tabcolsep\relax}}{\lipsum[75]}
  \end{tabularx}
 }
 \\\hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Ok, it is better now. But if I change something later, I have to go change `.9` to something else I am sure.

The question is: Is this really how one is supposed to do this in Latex? It seems that Latex should have a way to do this automatically. Is there a better approach I should be looking at instead of what I am doing above?

The above is a small example. I want to use tabularx and have other tabularx tables inside as well. So this can get complicated very quickly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need multicolumn here, your text is just a paragraph the full width of the outer table column.  (Incidentally as I've commented before I wouldn't use tabularx for the inner column: in a table where every column is an `X` column, you know in advance the column widths, so there is no need to make tabularx work them out (although it works).

```
\documentclass[10pt,notitlepage]{article}%
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}|l|Y|@{}}\hline
 column 1 &
 {\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}Y|Y|Y@{}}\hline
       \lipsum[75] &  \lipsum[75] &   \lipsum[75] \\\hline
  \end{tabularx}
 }

\lipsum[75]
 \\\hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a way to achieve the objective. The default size of each single column is `\hsize`. To change it, use `>{\setlength\hsize{1\hsize}}`. As to the 3-column width, one needs to set it to 3 times the basic `\hsize` because it takes up 3 columns.

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass[10pt,notitlepage]{article}%
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}|l|Y|@{}}\hline
 column 1 &{
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{Y|Y|Y}%
\lipsum[75] &\lipsum[75] & \lipsum[75] \\ \hline
\multicolumn{3}{>{\centering\setlength\hsize{3\hsize}}Y}{\lipsum[75]}
\end{tabularx}}\\ \hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You're forgetting the space taken by the rules and the intercolumn spaces, so `\setlength{\hsize}{\dimexpr3\hsize+2\arrayrulewidth+4\tabcolsep\relax}` should give a better result.

Comment: @egreg Are you referring to the setting '\setlength\hsize{1\hsize}}X@{}' that I should consider ?

Comment: I'm referring to the call inside `\multicolumn`.

Comment: @egreg Just tried your suggestion, both look the same to my naked eyes. Your suggestion will keep in mind, thanks.

Comment: Based on @Jesse, perhaps we could define the new column type as `\newcolumntype{Y}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash\setlength\hsize{#1\hsize}}X}`, then we can simply use `Y{}` for `Y`, and `Y{3}` for spanning three auto sized columns.