# Justified text and multicolumn size in tabularx

Tags: tables, tabularx, multicolumn

I'd like to create table with (a lot of) justified text and some multicolumns. 
My example is below. It works more or less... but

1. I get lots of underfull \hbox notices, which I think it's because the text is not flushedleft... how do I get rid of them? (I don't want my text flushed left}
2. I am not sure about how I did the multicolumn, I just want it to span over two columns. Is there a better way of doing it?

I saw this [What is the correct way to calculate \multicolumn size when using tabularx?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/151261/what-is-the-correct-way-to-calculate-multicolumn-size-when-using-tabularx) but the mulitcolumn does not look quite right to me.

Thanks!

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,fleqn]{book}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tabularx,calc} 
\usepackage{adjustbox} 
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multicol}%,tocbibind, ,fullpage,lastpage,framed}
\usepackage{multirow,booktabs}


\def\tabularxcolumn#1{m{#1}} %defines the X column to use m (\parbox[c]) instead of p (`parbox[t]`).

\begin{document}



\begin{table}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{5 pt}
\begin{center}
  \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{  X  X  X }
\toprule
\multicolumn{1}{c}{A} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{B}  & \multicolumn{1}{c}{C} \\
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus
&
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus
& 
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus\\ 

\multicolumn{2}{m{0.66\linewidth-2\tabcolsep}}{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus} &
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus\\    

\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{center}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I find find any problem with your code. The underfull `\hbox`es might just be because you're using "Lorem ipsum..." text, for which hyphenation is not properly defined, coupled with the fact that your column width is fairly small.

Comment: I do have the same problem when I type real words!

Comment: Then it's a result of the narrow columns. Do they need to be so narrow? What about adjusting the page boundary margins using [`geometry`](http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry)?

Comment: mmm I am not sure, I don't think they are narrow, they are just 3 column as wide as the page with linewidth.

Comment: but I think you are right @Werner. It is probably an hyphenation problem due to having text in 'narrow' columns. I can't make them any larger and I don't want to change my page margins. I think if I want justified text like that in a table I will have to keep the notices. In fact if I do raggedright like David suggested I don't get the warnings... but not even the text like I want it. Thanks!

Comment: They are just *warnings*. However, one could also adjust your inter-word spacing to accommodate for shorter-than-expected lines due to the justification. What happens when you include the [`microtype` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/microtype) in your preamble?

Comment: I tried, i get the same number of warnings!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use

```
 \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{*3{>{\sloppy\arraybackslash} X }}
```

and

```
\multicolumn{2}{m{0.66\linewidth-2\tabcolsep}}{\sloppy Lorem...
```

use a ragged setting in the narrow columns to avoid the warnings, such as `\raggedright` instead of `\sloppy`. 
Or modify the value of `\hbadness` within the table (`\hbadness=`...)

the multiclolumn width setting is sort of OK as you know in advance the widths, as you have `XXX` but that implies you could (and perhaps should) do the same at the top level and not use `tabularx` at all, and just use `m` columns of a fixed width.

If you need to span two `X` columns of unknown width you can use

```
   \multicolumn{2}{>{\sloppy\setlength\hsize{\dimexpr 2\hsize+2\tabcolsep\relax}}X}{Lorem..}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. The raggedright solution does not work for me because I want my text justified like in the example. The other solution '\multicolumn{2}{X}{\setlength\hsize{2\hsize+2\tabcolsep} Lorem...' gives me errors! With 'tabular' and 'm' columns it works setting ' \begin{tabular}{  m{3.5cm}  m{3.5cm}  m{3.5cm} }' and  '\multicolumn{2}{m{7cm+2\tabcolsep}}{Lorem...}' but I still get the notices about the underfull '\hbox'

Comment: @esperluette ok replace \raggedright by whatever paragraph setting you want eg `\sloppy`

Comment: @DavidCarlise I get the same number of bad boxes as in the original case. Is there a way I can maybe relax the constraints just within the table so I don't see the warnings?  (and just see other more important ones!) Otherwise I think it looks ok... even if the text is a little "stretched"

Comment: @esperluette lots of ways http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/50830/do-i-have-to-care-about-bad-boxes/50850#50850

Comment: @DavidCarlise Thank you very much, adding a `\hbadness=10000` (!!) after \begin{table} did the trick! And does not change the settings for the rest of the document.

Comment: @DavidCarlise Will just have to be careful... It's the first time I ask a question. What should I do now? may I add to your answer the solution that worked for me? or just leave it to the comments?

Comment: Up to you: if you think what you finally did  is sufficiently different feel free to answer (and accept your own answer) It's always nice to get a green tick but I don't actually need the points:-)

Comment: @jon I decided to let your edit stand but the original was also correct.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle -- Ah, sorry. I thought it was an oversight..!